# rails creating temporary objects with ids

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form

I am trying to find a solution the above problem.

Basically, I have a model 'Job', which has and belongs to many contacts and locations. When a user begins creating a new job, they should be able to begin adding locations and contacts to the new record. The problem is when I try save the record. How can a user associate location and contact records to a job record that doesn't yet have an ID? The error message I get on the create action is this,

For every contact I try to add I get a

```
  Validation failed: Job contacts is invalid
```

Which i guess comes from the fact a Job ID doesn't exist at the time of assignment.

The parameters that come through to the controller are all within the job_params, which is how I want them to be received. This is aided with SimpleForm, which has the handy 'association' method for habtm records. If possible I would like to keep everything within a form object using simple form (not using field_tags etc). So for example the contact field looks like this.

```
=f.association :contacts, collection: job.client.contacts, as: :check_boxes
```

So what are my options? Is there something I can do differently?

I had considered the following:

1. Creating a record in the new action and setting it with a flag to state its invalidity until the necessary fields have been populated. At which point it can become a 'proper' record, but this feels as though it has the potential to get quite messy.
2. Using STI to start a dummy record?

Maybe I'm way off piste with all this, but even some direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the users id to the job. Then, when looking for jobs for the user do

```
jobs = Job.where("user_id = ?", user.id)
```